# scalding testing job with JobTest and Csv(skipHeader = true) input

Tags: scalding

I have this job:

```
import com.twitter.scalding.{Args, Csv, Job}

class ManagersAndTeams(args: Args) extends Job(args)
{
    val managersPipe = Csv(args("managers"), skipHeader = true)
        .project('managerID, 'teamID)

    val teamsPipe = Csv(args("teams"), skipHeader = true)
        .project('teamID, 'name)
        .rename('teamID, 'teamID_)

    managersPipe.joinWithLarger(('teamID, 'teamID_), teamsPipe)
        .project('teamID, 'name, 'managerID)
        .write(Csv(args("output"), writeHeader = true))
}
```

And I am trying to test it. But during test it doesn't seem to read the csv headers:

```
Caused by: cascading.tuple.TupleException: unable to select from: [UNKNOWN], using selector: ['managerID', 'teamID']
    at cascading.tuple.Tuple.get(Tuple.java:364)
    at cascading.flow.stream.OperatorStage$1.makeResult(OperatorStage.java:92)
    at cascading.flow.stream.FunctionEachStage.receive(FunctionEachStage.java:95)
    at cascading.flow.stream.FunctionEachStage.receive(FunctionEachStage.java:39)
    at cascading.flow.stream.SourceStage.map(SourceStage.java:102)
    at cascading.flow.stream.SourceStage.call(SourceStage.java:53)
    at cascading.flow.stream.SourceStage.call(SourceStage.java:38)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: cascading.tuple.FieldsResolverException: could not select fields: [{1}:'managerID'], from: [{?}:UNKNOWN]
    at cascading.tuple.Fields.indexOf(Fields.java:1016)
    at cascading.tuple.Fields.translatePos(Fields.java:957)
    at cascading.tuple.Fields.getPos(Fields.java:939)
    at cascading.tuple.Tuple.getPos(Tuple.java:373)
    at cascading.tuple.Tuple.get(Tuple.java:360)
    ... 10 more
```

This is my test class:

```
import com.twitter.scalding.{Csv, JobTest}
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import org.scalatest.Matchers._

class ManagersAndTeamsSuite extends FunSuite
{
    test("joins") {
        createJob(
            List(
                ("managerID", "teamID", "x"),
                ("man1", "team1", "x1"),
                ("man2", "team2", "x2")
            ),
            List(
                ("teamID", "name", "y"),
                ("team1", "the team 1", "y1"),
                ("team2", "the team 2", "y2")
            )
        ) should be(List(

        ))
    }

    def createJob(
        managers: List[(String, String, String)],
        teams: List[(String, String, String)]
        ) = {
        var r = List.empty[(String, String, String)]
        new JobTest(new ManagersAndTeams(_))
            .arg("managers", "managers-arg")
            .arg("teams", "teams-arg")
            .arg("output", "output-arg")
            .source(Csv("managers-arg", skipHeader = true), managers)
            .source(Csv("teams-arg", skipHeader = true), teams)
            .sink[(String, String, String)](Csv("output-arg", writeHeader = true)) {
            buffer =>
                r = buffer.toList
        }.run.finish
        r
    }
}
```

As you can see, I got skipHeaders=true both in the job and test (I also tried the test without them but getting the same issue). Debugging the scalding/cascading code, it seems it doesn't parse the headers of the csv, as defined in the test. Any ideas on how this can be resolved?

Comment: no unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

It does now work in test mode.  Must be a bug.  Don't have enough time to debug it.  You can see how it works through the scalding scripts in local mode in: https://gist.github.com/ceteri/4371896, and same works well in hdfs mode.  Need to file this as a bug + fix.